# Export hql output to csv in beeline

Tags: bash, csv, hive, hiveql, beeline

I am trying to export my hql output to csv in beeline using below command :

```
beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://****/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2"?tez.queue.name=devices-jobs  --outputformat=csv2 -e "use schema_name; select * from table_name where open_time_new>= '2020-07-13' and open_time_new < '2020-07-22'" > filename.csv
```

The problem is that some column values in the table contains commas which pushes the data of same column to the next column value.
For eg:

```
| abcd  | as per data,outage fault,xxxx. 
| xyz  |as per the source,ghfg,hjhjg.
```

The above data will get saved as 4 column instead of 2.
Need help!

Answer (score 1):

Try [the approach with local directory](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Writingdataintothefilesystemfromqueries):

```sql
insert overwrite local directory '/tmp/local_csv_report'
row format delimited fields terminated by "," escaped by '\\'
select * 
  from table_name 
 where open_time_new >= '2020-07-13' 
   and open_time_new < '2020-07-22'
```

This will create several csv files under your local `/tmp/local_csv_report` directory, so using simple `cat` after that will merge the results into a single file.